# Random number generation seemingly not working properly

Tags: arrays, vb.net, random

There's a thing that's happening that I don't understand the reason behind.

In Visual Basic, I've got a 2D Integer array that I populate with random numbers. When I do it with Rnd():

```
For j = 0 To matrix.GetUpperBound(0)
  For i = 0 To matrix.GetUpperBound(1)
    matrix(j, i) = 1 + CType((Rnd() * 50), Integer)
  Next
Next
```

It always writes the same numbers in the same position in the matrix.

But when I do it with the Random class:

```
Dim r As Random = New Random()
For j = 0 To matrica.GetUpperBound(0)
  For i = 0 To matrica.GetUpperBound(1)
    matrica(j, i) = r.Next(0, 100)
  Next
Next
```

It does what it's supposed to.

I don't understand why in the first case I get the same numbers in the same position every time I run the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, you need to seed the Random number generator using Randomize() call. Check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.vbmath.randomize?view=netframework-4.7.2)